# How to figure out how javascript dynamically changes a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, web-scraping

On the following URL, the table (with the header `Gene Name Gene ID Genetic Modification Type   State   Price   Turnaround Time`) is dynamically generated.

https://apac.cyagen.com/services/crispr-knockout-mouse-sperm-bank.html?q=104183

If one checks chrome devtools, it can be seen that a POST request to `https://bio.cyagen.net/api/bio/sperm-bank/search/` is sent which results the following output (prettified). But it is not clear to me how this JSON data is converted to the table shown on the webpage (i.e, which fields in the JSON object are used.) Could anybody let me now the most efficient way to figure this out? Thanks.

```
{
  "exact": {
    "_shards": {
      "failed": 0,
      "successful": 5,
      "total": 5
    },
    "hits": {
      "hits": [
        {
          "_id": "AWbtC4w1Ls3QbU422f2l",
          "_index": "biodata3",
          "_score": 15.089622,
          "_source": {
            "cas9_cko": true,
            "cas9_cko_pro": "cas9_cko_planning",
            "cell_line": "C57BL/6N",
            "cell_line_cko": "C57BL/6N",
            "cell_line_es_cko": "C57BL/6N",
            "chromosome_num": 3,
            "dbXrefs": "MGI:MGI:1341098|Ensembl:ENSMUSG00000063779|Vega:OTTMUSG00000016670",
            "description": "chitinase-like 4",
            "es_cko": false,
            "full_name_from_nomenclature_authority": "chitinase-like 4",
            "gene_id": "104183",
            "gene_symbol": "Chil4",
            "id": 4308989,
            "live_gene": false,
            "locus_tag": "-",
            "map_location": "3|3 F2.2",
            "mgi_url": "http://www.informatics.jax.org/reference/marker/MGI:1341098?typeFilter=Literature",
            "modification_date": "20160426",
            "name": "Mus musculus",
            "nomenclature_status": "O",
            "number": "06588",
            "other_designations": "chitinase 3-like 4, Chil4;chitinase-3-like protein 4;secreted protein Ym2",
            "product_id": "KOCMP-06588-Chil4",
            "special_cko": false,
            "species_type": "Popular species",
            "spermbank_gene": true,
            "spermbank_gene_pro": "cas9_ko",
            "symbol_from_nomenclature_authority": "Chil4",
            "synonyms": "Chi3l4;Ym2",
            "taxonomy_id": "10090",
            "taxonomy_score": 25,
            "transcript_cnt_nm": 1,
            "transcript_cnt_nr": 0,
            "transcript_cnt_xm": 0,
            "transcript_cnt_xr": 0,
            "type_of_gene": "protein-coding",
            "vb_abbreviation": "m",
            "vb_name": "Mouse"
          },
          "_type": "gene-info-201708",
          "order": 1
        }
      ],
      "max_score": 15.089622,
      "total": 1
    },
    "timed_out": false,
    "took": 1
  },
  "fuzzy": {
    "_shards": {
      "failed": 0,
      "successful": 5,
      "total": 5
    },
    "hits": {
      "hits": [],
      "max_score": null,
      "total": 0
    },
    "timed_out": false,
    "took": 3
  }
}
```

Comment: The **Network** panel of the devtools has an "initiator" column-- you can use that to see from where in the code the request is being made.  Place a breakpoint there you can step through to see what happens with the response.

Comment: @AlexanderNied That sounds like an answer.

Comment: @Brilliand - you're right, I was just being lazy   I've posted a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the Chrome Devtools Network Pane:

[image: Chrome DevTools Network Pane With Initiator Column Highlighted]

There is an **Initiator** column that shows you from where in code the resource was requested.  If the column isn't present for you you can add/remove columns by right-clicking a column header and using the context menu provided.

You can click directly into the place in code the request was initiated from, or you can hover the entry and get a stack trace from the request:

[image: Initiator Entry Stack Trace Shown On Hover]

I would recommend loading the page with the devtools open and the Network pane capturing requests.  Find the entry for resource you are interested in (you can filter down to XHR requests or filter with a string).  Hover the initiator entry to find the best place to drop a breakpoint, and click to open it in the sources pane.  From there, you can place a breakpoint in the debugger and step through what happens with the resource after it is returned to get a sense for how it is being processed.  Good luck!

Comment: I just see `https://apac.cyagen.com/services/crispr-knockout-mouse-sperm-bank.html?q=104183` in the initiator of `https://bio.cyagen.net/api/bio/sperm-bank/search/`. When click `https://apac.cyagen.com/services/crispr-knockout-mouse-sperm-bank.html?q=104183`, it just shows me its HTML content. I still don't know which code initiate the POST request. Would you please demonstrate how you decipher this with more details? Thanks.

Comment: @user1424739 - that link redirects me to the homepage for the site.

Comment: Could you change to an Asia IP via VPN? I think the website is only for Asia Pacific, so they required an Asia IP address.